# How to replace a number with another number using a dictionary of replacements in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace

I have two columns of numbers: one column a record of student SAT scores, and another, their corresponding scores on the ACT test in a python pandas dataframe.

```
     SAT Score  ACT Score
0       2160.0       32.0
1       1890.0        NaN
2       1720.0       27.0
3       2160.0       34.0
4       2150.0       32.0
5       1310.0       31.0
6       2220.0        NaN
7       2250.0        NaN
8       2170.0        NaN
9       2080.0        NaN
10      2310.0       34.0
```

The dictionary I have created looks like this:

```
score_dict = {"36": 2390, "35":2330, "34": 2260, "33": 2170, "32": 2110, "31": 2040, "30": 1990, "29":1920, "28": 1850, "27": 1810, "26": 1760, "25":1700, "24": 1640, "23": 1570, "22": 1530}"}
```

I'd like to replace dict keys with their respective dict values when either SAT or ACT scores are missing. I'm not sure how to finish the code.

```
M = df['SAT Score']
N = df['ACT Score']

for index in range(len(M)):
    i = N[index]
    k = M[index]
    if k != k *1:
       for key, value in score_dict.items():
            ....
```

This is as far as I got.

I have some NaN values in the SAT Column. My logic was to first look at SAT scores with NaNs in them (k != k*1), then for those rows look at the corresponding ACT scores. I would then use dictionary to look replace the missing SAT scores with the corresponding ACT scores by using
 the dictionary.

Comment: What is `if k != k *1:` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: I have some NaN values in the SAT Column. My logic was to first look at SAT scores with NaNs in them, then for those rows look at the corresponding ACT scores. I would then use dictionary to look replace the missing SAT scores with the corresponding ACT scores in the dictionary.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data-frame? What you are trying to do should be done using `pandas` vectorized operations, not for-loops.

Comment: unless you are stuck with a really old version of Python you should be using `math.isnan()` to check for `NaN` values, as that makes the intent of your code a lot clearer

Comment: Note, `for key, value in score_dict.items():` should make you pause and think, "Am I using this `dict` correctly"? Do you *really* want to iterate over all the items in the dictionary? Pretty sure you need to use your dictionary as a *map*

Comment: @UnholySheep in this case, using a `pandas` container, this shoudl be done using `df['column_name'].isnull()`

Comment: I have uploaded the sample dataframe

Comment: @HaebichanJung and `score_dict`...? Why are the keys *strings*. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: A dict *is* a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `pandas`, rely on `pandas` operations. You almost never want to use a for-loop.

So, given:

```
In [56]: df
Out[56]:
       SAT   ACT
0   2160.0  32.0
1   1890.0   NaN
2   1720.0  27.0
3   2160.0  34.0
4   2150.0  32.0
5   1310.0  31.0
6   2220.0   NaN
7   2250.0   NaN
8   2170.0   NaN
9   2080.0   NaN
10  2310.0  34.0

In [58]: score_dict
Out[58]:
{1530: 22,
 1570: 23,
 1640: 24,
 1700: 25,
 1760: 26,
 1810: 27,
 1850: 28,
 1920: 29,
 1990: 30,
 2040: 31,
 2110: 32,
 2170: 33,
 2260: 34,
 2330: 35,
 2390: 36}
```

Note, I had to reverse the mapping of the dict you provided, since that one mapped ACT scores (curiously, as *strings*) to SAT scores, but you need it the other way around if the ACT scores are the ones with `NaN`.

Anyway, to do selection, e.g. where ACT is NaN, us `.isnull` and `loc` based selection:

```
In [66]: df.loc[df.ACT.isnull(),'ACT']
Out[66]:
1   NaN
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
Name: ACT, dtype: float64
```

Now, if you want to use a dict to map value, the `pd.Series.map` method does this automatically:

```
In [67]: df.loc[df.ACT.isnull(), 'SAT'].map(score_dict)
Out[67]:
1     NaN
6     NaN
7     NaN
8    33.0
9     NaN
```

Name: SAT, dtype: float64

So, you can just use the above to replace (Note, your dict only covered one case...)

```
In [68]: df.loc[df.ACT.isnull(),'ACT'] = df.loc[df.ACT.isnull(), 'SAT'].map(score_dict)

In [69]: df
Out[69]:
       SAT   ACT
0   2160.0  32.0
1   1890.0   NaN
2   1720.0  27.0
3   2160.0  34.0
4   2150.0  32.0
5   1310.0  31.0
6   2220.0   NaN
7   2250.0   NaN
8   2170.0  33.0
9   2080.0   NaN
10  2310.0  34.0
```

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you very much! I immediately understood by what you meant by string. Such a dumb mistake. Just wondering; let's say that I want to then turn ACT scores into categories: Top 1%, Top 5%, etc. In this case, I would also only rely on pandas functions too? No for loops?

Comment: @HaebichanJung you should ask a different question, it's not well related to this one, and merits it's own.

Comment: @HaebichanJung although, you can play around with `df.ACT.rank(pct=True)` Although, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do. So again, probably merits it's own question, that would include a [mcve]

Comment: Ha! I knew you were amazing. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly the answer you're looking for. But at the very least, it may be helpful to see how subsetting DataFrames work and how to use the `map` function on such a DataFrame.

First let's do some setup

```
>>> score_dict = {'36': 2390, '35': 2330, '34': 2260, '33':2200}
>>> invert_score_dict = {v:k for k, v in score_dict.items()}
>>> data1 = [["Bob", "36"], ["Nancy", "35"], ["Billy", "34"], ["Suzy", "33"]]
>>> data2 = [["Bob", 2390], ["Nancy", 2330], ["Billy", 2260], ["Rachel", 2200]]
>>> act = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns=['name', 'score'])
>>> sat = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, columns=['name', 'score'])
>>> act
    name score
0    Bob    36
1  Nancy    35
2  Billy    34
3   Suzy    33
>>> sat
     name  score
0     Bob   2390
1   Nancy   2330
2   Billy   2260
3  Rachel   2200
```

Now I'm making some assumptions here since I don't know what your DFs look like. But it should at least bit a bit illustrative.

```
>>> act.merge(sat, on=['name'], how='outer', suffixes=['_act', '_sat']indicator='exists_in')
     name score_act  score_sat   exists_in
0     Bob      36   2390.0        both
1   Nancy      35   2330.0        both
2   Billy      34   2260.0        both
3    Suzy      33      NaN   left_only
4  Rachel     NaN   2200.0  right_only
```

Here I'm just merging them so I can make sure they're in the same DataFrame.

Below I'm just using pandas `loc` to help grab a subset of the DataFrame and fill in with default values based on the `score_dict` and `inverted_score_dict`

```
>>> merged_scores.loc[merged_scores.score_sat.isnull(), 'score_sat'] = 
merged_scores.score_act.map(score_dict)

>>> merged_scores
name score_act  score_sat   exists_in
0     Bob        36     2390.0        both
1   Nancy        35     2330.0        both
2   Billy        34     2260.0        both
3    Suzy        33     2200.0   left_only
4  Rachel       NaN     2200.0  right_only
>>> merged_scores.loc[merged_scores.score_act.isnull(), 'score_act'] = 
merged_scores.score_sat.map(invert_score_dict)
>>> merged_scores
     name score_act  score_sat   exists_in
0     Bob        36     2390.0        both
1   Nancy        35     2330.0        both
2   Billy        34     2260.0        both
3    Suzy        33     2200.0   left_only
4  Rachel        33     2200.0  right_only
```

Comment: Oh it looks like the original post was edited to have a sample DF. So the merge function call is a moot point. But the last blurb of my post is hopefully still helpful.